# Reading logs from remote server over ssh

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I am trying to ssh to a particular port on a server and read the logs but the ssh connection to server closed after authentication immediately when we try to execute it through python subprocess.

I am using following command to read the logs:

sshpass -p xxxx ssh -tt -v root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p 2200 | tee -i -a remoteserver.log

Trace log:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: tty_make_modes: no fd or tio
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.x closed.
Transferred: sent 1808, received 1440 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 36560.7, received 29119.1
debug1: Exit status 0
```

PS: This command works fine when we execute it directly on terminal.

Anyone has faced similar issue?

Comment: How does your `subprocess` command looks like ?

Comment: @user56700 with subprocess its able to authenticate. In trace log I can see 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password)
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: tty_make_modes: no fd or tio
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0

debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.x closed.
...
debug1: Exit status 0

Comment: @mrutyunjay I see, I still think subprocess is the culprit though, but If you get this to work, please share an answer.

Comment: @mrutyunjay You should at least share the code you use to execute the command or create a working example of it with simplified code.

Comment: `debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).` and `debug1: Exit status 0`, make me guess everything is fine. What do you expect to happen and what is happening ?

Comment: it should wait for some time and read the logs populated on 2200 port. as soon as it logs in, server/client closes the connection. it does not wait.

Comment: Aren't you re-inventing the wheel? Isn't there tooling to do this, e.g. Ansible.

Comment: It looks like you're successfully capturing the debug output of the `ssh` process. It's successfully connecting, authenticating, and then exiting because it has nothing to do. It's not clear what else you're looking for. You keep talking about "logs". What logs? Are you trying to capture logs from some other process?

Comment: Put `-vvv` to see even more debug logs.